# MIME-type information without .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mime-types

currently I am trying to host some videos embedded with html5 video-tag. The focus for this is to provide it (as far as possible) browser- , flash- and OS- independent.
I embedded webM, mp4 and ogg versions to provide maximum browser-coverage. 
It works perfectly for iOS, Mac and Windows with multiple browsers.

However only Linux (tried Firefox and Conqueror) is refusing to play the videos. The error message displayed is that the MIME-types are not supported.

The solution i found so far is to add those MIME-types via a .htacces-file. Unfortunately there is at the moment no possibilty to use a .htaccess on the server and the Flash-fallback is not called because Firefox actually supports the video-tag.

My question is if there is any other way to provide those information allowing browsers on Linux to play the videos?

Comment: Are you specifying a `type` attribute on the `source` element?

Comment: PS why still use OGG? WebM and h.264 will cover all up-to-date browsers.